# Hide the image onmouseover

Tags: javascript, html

i want the iframe to appear but the image to go onmouseover
if that makes sense?
id prefer to have it done in javasript

```
<html>  
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function makeFrame(src) {
ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
ifrm.setAttribute("src","http://www.google.com");
ifrm.style.display = "block";
ifrm.style.width = 640+"px";
ifrm.style.height = 480+"px";
document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
}

function closeFrame(){
ifrm.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="images/largepic.jpg" onmouseover=makeFrame() onmouseout=closeFrame() height="100px" width="100px" />
</body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: javascript might not be the best tool for this... I bet there's a simple CSS solution for this

Comment: If you hide something `onmouseover`, `onmouseout` will trigger immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
function makeFrame(src) {
    ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
    ifrm.setAttribute("src","http://www.google.com");
    ifrm.style.display = "block";
    ifrm.style.width = 640+"px";
    ifrm.style.height = 480+"px";
    document.body.replaceChild(ifrm, document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]);
}
```

Although I'd suggest, in this case, giving the `img` element an `id` or otherwise uniquely reference it) in order to accurately know which `img` element you're going to remove.

If, instead, you simply want to hide the image once the `iframe` is inserted:

```
function makeFrame(src) {
    ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
    ifrm.setAttribute("src","http://www.google.com");
    ifrm.style.display = "block";
    ifrm.style.width = 640+"px";
    ifrm.style.height = 480+"px";
    document.body.insertBefore(ifrm, document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]);
}
```

With the CSS:

```
iframe + img {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Well, yes; but that's precisely what you asked for (given your current code). Now, if you'd like to [post a live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you're working with we can maybe offer a sensible solution (that meets your needs, rather than just doing what you asked it to do).

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass the "this" parameter into the closeFrame function call which will give you the image element. You can then just set `display: none` on that element:

```
<html>  
  <head>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function makeFrame(image_element) { <!-- Take the image_element as a parameter -->
    image_element.style.display = "none"; <!-- Set image element to not display -->
    ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    ifrm.setAttribute("src","http://www.google.com");
    ifrm.style.display = "block";
    ifrm.style.width = 640+"px";
    ifrm.style.height = 480+"px";
    document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
    }

    function closeFrame(){
    ifrm.style.display = "none";
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Pass this into makeFrame where this is the image element -->
    <img src="images/largepic.jpg" onmouseover=makeFrame(this) onmouseout=closeFrame() height="100px" width="100px" />
  </body>
</html>
```

as Shmiddty said, the `closeframe()` will be called as soon as you set `display: none` as . You probably want to set an onmouseout event on the iframe itself rather than on the img element.

---

Updating my answer based on the OP's comments:

Here is the code required to close the IFrame when moving the mouse out of it. This also restores the original image.

```
<html>  
  <head>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function makeFrame(image_element) { <!-- Take the image_element as a parameter. -->
    image_element.style.display = "none"; <!-- Set image element to not display. -->
    ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    ifrm.setAttribute("src","http://www.google.com");
    ifrm.style.display = "block";
    ifrm.style.width = 640+"px";
    ifrm.style.height = 480+"px";
    ifrm.onmouseout=closeFrame; <!-- Close the IFrame when the mouse moves out of it. -->
    document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
    }

    function closeFrame(){
      ifrm.style.display = "none";
      var image_element = document.getElementById("myImg"); <!-- Show the image that was hidden when showing the iframe. -->
      image_element.style.display = "inline";
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Pass this into makeFrame where this is the image element -->
    <img id="myImg" src="images/largepic.jpg" onmouseover=makeFrame(this) height="100px" width="100px" />
  </body>
</html>
```

This works by binding an `onmouseout` event to the IFrame. This tells the browser to call the `closeFrame` function when moving the mouse out of the IFrame. In the `closeFrame` function we then restore the image that was previously hidden.

Comment: sorry im a newbie to this. i need frame to stay

Comment: When do you want the frame to close? When you move the mouse out of it?